# Provide PV function content when constructing object in C++

Tags: c++, class, pure-virtual

In Java you can create an object whilst at the same time providing (or overloading) abstract functions within the object, thus:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Whatever in here
    }
};
```

I really like that way of doing it, and was wondering if there was some similar construct in C++.

Basically I want a base class with a couple of PV functions declared in it (amongst other stuff), and the user to create an instance of that class whilst at the same time providing the body of the PV functions.

I know I could create child classes, but that seems a little clunky for what I need, where each child class would be unique and only be used to make one instance each.

I have thought about providing lamdas to the constructor and using those instead of actual member functions, but that really seems messy and hard for a novice user to get their head around - not to mention that it would be too rigid (I'd also like to be able to override some non-pure virtual functions optionally).

So is child classes the only way to go, or is there some lesser-known construct in some newer C++ standard that I don't know about that could do what I want?

---

To expand a little - the idea is to have a class like:

```
class Thread {
    // other stuff
    public:
        virtual void setup() = 0;
        virtual void loop() = 0;
        // other functions, some virtual but not pure
};

Thread threadOne {
    void setup() {
        // Init code for this thread
    }
    void loop() {
        // Run code for this thread
    }
};

Thread threadTwo {
    void setup() {
        // Init code for this thread
    }
    void loop() {
        // Run code for this thread
    }
};
```

Obviously not that syntax, but it gives you an idea of how I'd like to use the class.

It's intended to be run on an embedded system with a slimmed-down C++ implementation (it's g++ but without the full STL). End users aren't the brightest bunch, so it has to be kept as simple to understand as possible.

---

Anonymous child classes are the closest to what I'd like (though still not perfect). I can use CPP macros to help abstract some of the class implementation syntactic sugar which would help.

---

Here's a compilable construct I have come up with. Is there anything "wrong" with this approach given the constraints above?

```
#define THREAD(NAME, CONTENT) class : public Thread {\
    public:\
CONTENT\
} NAME;


class Thread {
    private:
        uint32_t stack[256]; // 1kB stack
        volatile bool _running;

    public:
        virtual void setup() = 0;
        virtual void loop() = 0;

        void start();
        void stop();
        uint8_t state();

        static void spawn(Thread *thr);
        void threadRunner();
};

void Thread::spawn(Thread *thread) {
    thread->threadRunner();
}

void Thread::start() {
    Thread::spawn(this);
}

void Thread::threadRunner() {
    _running = true;
    setup();
    while (_running) {
        loop();
    }
}

void Thread::stop() {
    _running = false;
}

uint8_t Thread::state() {
    return 0;
}

THREAD(myThread,
    void setup() override {

    }

    void loop() override {

    }
)

void setup() {
    myThread.start();
}

void loop() {
}
```

Obviously it doesn't actually *do* anything yet - the whole of the threading back-end is a separate issue, and will be ported over from some existing code I wrote a few years back.   I am mainly interested in simplifying the interface for the end user.

Comment: You could use anonymous classes, but I would stick to the lambdas.

Comment: @Vorac Anonymous classes look to be my favourite option at the moment.

Comment: I would advise against that. The current 'fashion' in C++ is as follows. Avoid macros at all costs. Avoid inheritance, if you can use composition. Use functional languages approaches such as passing functions around or `fold`ing containers through stl algorithms. Lastly, virtual tables are a bother for reasons such as slicing, diamonds, efficiency, impossibility to overload virtual methods.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: From your updated question, I can see you want to implement flexible threads. I have seen many **horrible** implementations of custom threading in C++ and am sure that I can **not** write a good one. Please pirate or purchase 'Scott Meyers: Effective Modern C++'. Read chapter 7 (40 pages in total).

Comment: The threading is mostly in MIPS assembly. The C++ classes are just a convenient container.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple possibilities, but I'd stick with something simple and versatile: callbacks and lambdas instead of virtual function and inheritance.

```
class ActionListener
{
    std::function<void(int)> _action_performed;
public:
    template<class CB>
    ActionListener(CB cb) : _action_performed(cb) {}

    void click() { _action_performed(0); }
};

int main()
{
    ActionListener al([](int n) { std::cout << "Action Performed #" << n << "\n"; });
    al.click(); // prints "Action Performed #0"
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01f6912aa3386171)

---

> I'd also like to be able to override some non-pure virtual functions optionally

Which, semantically speaking, means providing a default behavior. This is possible:

```
ActionListener(CB cb) : _action_performed(cb) {} // construct an AL with the given callback

ActionListener() : _action_performed(default_action_performed) {} // construct an AL with a default callback
void default_action_performed(int n) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Default values like that require specific ordering - you can't provide them by name and skip some to only provide certain functions in a list.

Comment: @Majenko Yes that is right. Unlike Java, there is no compiler support or syntactic sugar to do what you want. You must use other tools of the language. If you want to be able to pass multiple callbacks in an unspecified order, you'd want to pass a map of names<->functions.

Comment: @Majenko But you'd better ask yourself if it's the best way. Why would you want to avoid lambdas in the first place?

Comment: It's intended for an embedded system, and I'd like the end user to be able to copy-and-paste their existing single-threaded code directly into whatever construct without any significant modification. The end user generally is a bit thick in this case, and don't even know what lambdas even are. At the moment child classes look the closest match to the Java construct.  Also, things like STL don't exist.

Comment: @Majenko Saying so in your question would not have been a waste of typing... Anyway, C++ is *hard*. You cannot design tools for dumb developers, they'll shoot themselves in the foot anyway.

Comment: FYI, C++ without the Standard Library is not C++ anymore, since **the Standard Library is part of the language itself**.

Comment: I know that and you know that, but the designers of the system didn't know that when they designed it...  So we have to make the best we can, and making abstractions and libraries as simple to use as possible is all we can do...

Comment: `the Standard Library is part of the language itself` ... and very often omitted on embedded systems as it is far too resource hungry to be used reliably (imagine heap fragmentation on a system with 2k of RAM...)

Comment: @Majenko I know, but since you're asking a question on a specific case of C++, say so in the question itself.

Comment: Sure. I've fleshed that aspect of it out a little.

Answer (score 0):

well, as you already mentioned, one way would be child classes.

another way would be providing some std::functions (or lambdas), either in the constructor or have some set functions.

store the function as a member and call this once your "virtual" member function is called: If you want it optional:

```
class MyBase
{
public:
   MyBase();
   void SetFunc(const std::function<int()>& myFun)
   {
      m_myFun = myFun;
   }

   int MyVirtFunc()
   {
      if(m_myFun)
      {
         return m_myFun();
      }
      else
      {
         return 42;
      }
   }   
private:
   std::function<int()> m_myFun;
}
```

if you want the functions given mandatory, put them in the constructor:

```
class MyBase
{
public:
   MyBase(const std::function<int()>& myFun)
       : m_myFun(myFun) {}

   int MyVirtFun()   {  return m_myFun(); }
private:
   const std::function<int()> m_myFun;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid lambdas and setters if possible.

Comment: @Majenko if you want no setters, use the second example (provide functions in constructor). there are no lambdas within the code, just std::functions. you can put anything convertible to that in.

Comment: It's intended for an embedded system, and I'd like the end user to be able to copy-and-paste their existing single-threaded code directly into whatever construct without any significant modification. The end user generally is a bit thick in this case, and don't even know what lambdas even are. At the moment child classes look the closest match to the Java construct.  Also, things like STL don't exist.

Comment: @Majenko in that case go for the child-classes. make sure they use the "override" keyword for the functions overridden (this ensures a function with exact same signature exists in the base class).